# What could I summarize this c++ program??? It is a counting loop for vowels and digits

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, count, switch-statement

I'm an early beginner of c++. I developed a program but I would like to compare, trying to summarize the following code to practice my logic skills.

The program currently is working. The program counts the number the vowels and digits found in a user's input. The input normally has to be in one word but could be random. The special part here is that, when a "#" is identified, the program stops to count.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



main () { 
  char str[100];
  cin>>str;

 //Declaring values depending of the letter 
  int count_a = 0;
  int count_e = 0;
  int count_i = 0;
  int count_o = 0;
  int count_u = 0;
  int count_digit = 0; 

  int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '#' && str[i] != '\0') {
  //for(int i = 0; (str[i] != '#' && str[i] != '\0' ) ; i++) { //This loop is working identifyng one of the places of each 


   char input = str[i]; //Get character for character
    switch(input){
//letter a      
    case 'a':
    case 'A':       
    count_a++;
    break;
//letter e  
    case 'e':
    case 'E':   
    count_e++;
    break;  
//letter i
    case 'i':
    case 'I':   
    count_i++;
    break;
//letter o      
    case 'o':
    case 'O':   
    count_o++;
    break;
//letter u
    case 'u':
    case 'U':   
    count_u++;
    break;  
//digit
    case'1':
    case'2':
    case'3':
    case'4':
    case'5':
    case'6':
    case'7':
    case'8':
    case'9':
    case'0':    
   count_digit++;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
i++;
  }

   cout <<"a="<<count_a<< endl;
   cout <<"e="<<count_e<< endl;
   cout <<"i="<<count_i<< endl;
   cout <<"o="<<count_o<< endl;
   cout <<"u="<<count_u<< endl;
   cout << "Digit="<<count_digit<< endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

For example if I write ***aaAeeeghjfh12iOu#12qea*** my output will be:

> a=3
>   e=3
>   i=1
>   o=1
>   u=1
>   Digit=2

Comment: What do you mean by summarize?

Comment: I think he means refactoring. This is a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow

Comment: Hi user13493679. It is unclear what your actual question is and whether it is on-topic here. [help/on-topic]. You need to clarify. In case you mean refactoring then with what goal. Please consider the idea to ask for a review on the appropriate site instead. For now this is either unclear or off-topic here.

Comment: By the way, isn't `y` supposed to be a vowel too ?

Comment: "_Y is a consonant about 2.5% of the time, and a vowel about 97.5% of the time._" - Utterly confusing :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo what ? Can't it be both at the same time, such a quantum letter ?

Comment: @Cid :-) Indeed. `std::context_driven_quantum_char_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to store all your counts and then only print the values you're interested in:

```
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  std::string str;
  std::cin >> str;

  std::array<int, UCHAR_MAX> characters{};

  for (auto const ch : str) ++characters[static_cast<unsigned>(ch)];

  using namespace std::literals;
  for (unsigned char const ch : "aeiou"sv)
    std::printf("%c = %d\n", static_cast<char>(ch),
                characters[std::tolower(ch)] + characters[std::toupper(ch)]);

  std::printf("Digits = %d\n",
              std::accumulate(&characters['0'], &characters['9'] + 1, 0));
}
```

Learn more:

- [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
- [operator""sv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv)
- [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: *"I'm an early beginner of c++"* Commenting your code would be great for OP

Comment: @cid I think adding some links to explanations for the interesting parts should be enough for beginners to understand what's going on.

Comment: @cid Since this is community wikied now, please don't hesitate to improve it with comments or in any other way you find suitable.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to shorten the program in terms of lines of code,
you could use an if/else statement instead of the case statement:

Example: 
The

`case'1':
    case'2':
    case'3':
    case'4':
    case'5':
    case'6':
    case'7':
    case'8':
    case'9':
    case'0':`

Stuff could be shortened to a check if

```
input >= '0' && input <= '9'
```